# Show that the function $g$ is bijective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $~f\colon X \!\to\! \{i \in \mathbb{N}:\! 1 \leq i \leq n \}$ be a bijective function and $~x$ be an element of $~X$. Now define the function  $g\colon X-\{x\}\!\to\!\{i \in \mathbb{N}:\! 1 \leq i \leq n-1 \}$ by the following rule: for any $y \in X-\{x\}$, 
$g(y):=\left\{\begin{matrix}
f(y) & \text{if }f(y)<f(x)\\ 
f(y)-1& \text{if }f(y)>f(x)
\end{matrix}\right..~$ Show that $g$ is bijective.

I've proved that $g$ is injective, but when I try to show that it
is also surjective (thus showing that it is bijective) I have a difficulty.
Since I want to prove that $g$ is surjective (using the definition of surjectivity) I want to show that if $m$ is an element of $\{i \in \mathbb{N}:\! 1 \leq i \leq n-1 \}$ then there exists $y \in X-\{x\}$ such that $g(y)=m$. By the trichotomy of order for natural numbers there are three cases to examine: $m>f(x)$,$~m<f(x)$,$~m=f(x)$.
I've done the first two cases but I haven't been able to do the third ($m=f(x)$) so far so I would appreciate any hint about how to conclude this last step.

Best regards,

lorenzo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m = f(x)$, then $y = f^{-1}(m + 1)$ will have $g(y) = m$. Reason: $f(y) = m+1 > f(x)$, which means that $$g(y) = f(y) - 1 = m+1-1 = m.$$